# Cross-browser JS Filesystem API

Tags: javascript, mobile, cross-browser, html5-filesystem

I'm aware of the JS Filesystem API for reading/writing files in the Chrome sandbox.

But I cannot find a W3C standard that does the same, is there a cross-browser way to read/write files on major browsers?

Thanks

Comment: No, because that would be a major security hole. You wouldn't want a website starting to write files into your filesystem. So vendor specific solutions exist, like the one you mentioned. IE uses `ActiveX`. But there is no general standard.

Comment: I meant reading/writing in a sandbox, not on the local filesystem of the user.

Comment: The W3C File System API standard has been discontinued, so probably not.

Comment: The only cross-plattform solution to save data persistently I'm aware of is local / web storage, specified here : http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to use the [Indexed Database API](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/) (large data, and a-synchronous) as the [File System API](https://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/) is discontinued. [Web Storage API](https://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) can also work but it's synchronous and for small data.

Comment: Can the Indexed Database API provide similar persistence guarantees? (I.e.: data will not be cleared without explicit action by the user).

Comment: @Alec yes they are persistent.